# Help with: already initialized constant RUBY?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake

I'm running Ruby 1.9.2 and Rails 3.1 locally and I'm trying to fire up my app. Whenever I use rake (rake spec, rake cucumber, rake db:create) I get these warnings. What did I do wrong?

```
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:10: warning: already initialized constant RUBY
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:84: warning: already initialized constant LN_SUPPORTED
```

Thanks for any pointers in the right direction!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is caused when you are using Ruby 1.9.2 (that already comes with rake bundled) and you installed the `rake` gem, for example using bundler.

You can

1. uninstall the `rake` gem

   ```
   $ gem uninstall rake
   ```
2. If you use bundler, keep using bundler. In this case, the right syntax is

   ```
   $ bundle exec rake spec
   ```

   not

   ```
   $ rake spec
   ```

Comment: Thanks Simone, that's exactly what's causing it! Now I need only one more thing figured out (which is the more severe problem), and I'm off and running [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7368808/rails-s-wont-start-the-server-could-not-find-rails-0/7368839#7368839) ;)

Answer (score 0):

The warnings may fade if you prefix your calls to `rake` with `bundle exec`, i.e.

```
bundle exec rake spec
bundle exec rake cucumber
```

ian.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you've 1 unnecessary require 'rake' in your code